# Trouble passing data from database table to view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am filling an SQL table with a query and then trying to pass the data from the model (for the table) into the view. I am attempting to use a ViewModel to pass the data to the view in a Controller Action.

Here is the Model:

```
    public partial class Report
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> Amount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Date { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ReasonId { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

IEnumerable ViewModel:

```
public class ReportViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Action:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadValidationTable(HttpPostedFileBase csvFile)
    {
        //Unrelated Code to read a CSV into another database table goes here
        //But was removed so it wouldn't be confusing.


        var db = new Report();

        var reportModel = new ReportViewModel()
        {
            Reports = new List<Report>() {new Report()}
        };

        return View("Upload", reportModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@model Entities.Models.ReportViewModel

                    <table class="table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Number</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>Reason Id</th>
                <th>Notes</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in Model.Reports.Where(x => x.Id != null))
                        {
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Id
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Number
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Amount
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Date
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.ReasonId
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    @item.Notes
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        }
                    }
                    </tbody>
        </table>
```

But I get an exception when I try to return the View which says ReportViewModel is not assignable to model type IEnumerable ReportViewModel

So I am just trying to pass all the rows from the Report database to an HTML table in my view. Any help, or a better way to do this would be appreciated.

Comment: Just a gentle advice. Try to prepare a ViewModel in a controller and sent such prepared model to View. Make sure you have used query in controller only. Also, encapsulate `db` object withing `using(){}` so that it is closed when you depart to View. Don't let connection to database be still open in a View.

Comment: The query is in the controller. And okay, make the second change

Comment: Any other advice for simply getting the data from the database table into the view? I've been trying for too long just to get the data from the SQL table to display

Comment: If the database is prefileld

Comment: There's something else going on that you haven't posted the code for. For best results here, always do exact copy-pastes of your code, rather than trying to redact or decide for us what is and isn't important. Honestly, if you knew that, you wouldn't need our help. Anyways, somewhere, you have a view that is typed `IEnumerable<ReportViewModel>` and you're passing just `ReportViewModel` to it. It might be a partial, child action, or maybe just the view you *think* is being used is not actually the one being used. Either way, there's nothing here that explains it.